# How can I check filenames to avoid pushing them into array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have this code in my node script

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const backupPath = path.join( __dirname , 'wp-backup');
const excludedResources = ['.DS_Store', 'dep.js', 'node_modules'];
const wpFolders = [];
const wpFiles = [];

fs.readdir( __dirname, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
    if( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    files.forEach( (file, i) => {
      const srcPath = path.join( __dirname, file.name);
      const destPath = path.join( backupPath, file.name );
         //
         if( file.isDirectory() ) {
            console.log(file.name);
            if( !fs.existsSync( destPath ) ) {
              fs.mkdir( destPath, (err) => {
                wpFolders.push( srcPath );
              });
            }
          } else {
            console.log(file.name);
            wpFiles.push( srcPath );
          }
    });
});
```

After I've readed the folder contents where the script will be placed, I want to check for the file names to check and skip the files that are into the `excludedResources` array to be pushed into the designed array. What is the best javascript function I can use to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to check if the file name exists in the excludedResources array. This is easy using the indexOf function for arrays:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const backupPath = path.join( __dirname , 'wp-backup');
const excludedResources = ['.DS_Store', 'dep.js', 'node_modules'];
const wpFolders = [];
const wpFiles = [];

fs.readdir( __dirname, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
    if( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    for (let file of files) {
      // check if file name is in excluded files array
      if (excludedResources.indexOf(file.name) >= 0) {
          // yes, we skip this file
          continue;
      }

      const srcPath = path.join( __dirname, file.name);
      const destPath = path.join( backupPath, file.name );
         //
         if( file.isDirectory() ) {
            console.log(file.name);
            if( !fs.existsSync( destPath ) ) {
              fs.mkdir( destPath, (err) => {
                wpFolders.push( srcPath );
              });
            }
          } else {
            console.log(file.name);
            wpFiles.push( srcPath );
          }
    });
});
```

The indexOf function returns the index where the string was found in the array or -1 if not found. So if it exists the result will be index 0 or greater.

Notice that I rewrote
files.forEach( (file, i) => {
as
for (let file of files) {

It's just a modern way and makes it clear how to break or continue in loops.

If you want to use your
files.forEach( (file, i) => {

change continue to return but it does not make your code clear.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did good, you know the basic concept of how it should work.

What I would change, is adding return to the `ìf (err)` handling, so that we don't start iterating the files if we have an error.

Another improvement is that you could move the `console.log(file.name)` above of the if-else condition so it wouldn't have to be defined twice.